# when i install npm install this warning keep showing any solution for this

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

npm install nodemon

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {

npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'fileupload@0.2.1',

npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.4.6 < 0.7.0' },

npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.16.0', npm: '9.6.6' }

npm WARN EBADENGINE }

why it keep showing unsupported engine is there any solution to prevent this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.